# Как отобразить выбор количества товара возле кнопки "Добавить в корзину"? Wordpress, Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook

Отображать нужно в цикле. 
Wordpress, Woocommerce
На картинке снизу вывод в цикле стандартным файлом плагина content-product.php:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $product;

if ( empty( $product ) || ! $product->is_visible() ) {
    return;
}
?><!-- 
<li <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <span class="nxowoo-box"> -->
    <?php

    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' );
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="product_table">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" >
                <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="" style="max-width: 95px;"> 
            </a>
        </td>
        <td class="product_table"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" ><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
        <td class="product_table wider-cell2"><?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' ); ?></td>
        <td class="product-table wider-cell"><?php  do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' ); ?></td>
    </tr>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сформулируйте вопрос так, что бы стало понятно чего надо. И укажите чем и как создано то, что на скрине

Comment: Кнопка добавить в корзину в woocommerce выводится так: do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );
Вот я и подумал что есть хук на вывод количества.

Comment: Как вообще сформировано то, что на скрине. Тема, плагин? Названия. Впрочем я видел готовый плагин, который выведет товары в таком виде. Названия не помню. Плагин бесплатный из репо.

Comment: Тема i-craft, plugin WooCommerce. Базовый шаблон плагина.
Я лишь поменял верстку на таблицу:

Comment: Об этом всём надо в вопросе писать.

Comment: На англ. версии ответили, если кому интересно:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42561082/how-do-i-display-quantity-select-in-loop-in-woocommerce

Comment: Если помогли - не нужно писать в комментах спасибы. Нужно отметить вопрос решенным/полезным ;) Но Вам спасибо, что тут указали на решение в др. месте..

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой код выдрал из одного проекта. Проверил работоспособность только что на теме Storefront - работает. Возможно, стоит под свои условия подредактировать.

```
   // выбор количества при добавлении простых товаров в корзину с поддержкой AJAX на страницах категорий товаров
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'custom_woo_before_shop_link');
function custom_woo_before_shop_link() {
    add_filter('woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'custom_woo_loop_add_to_cart_link', 10, 2);
    add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'custom_woo_after_shop_loop');
}
// customise Add to Cart link/button for product loop
function custom_woo_loop_add_to_cart_link($button, $product) {
    // not for variable, grouped or external products
    if (!in_array($product->product_type, array('variable', 'grouped', 'external'))) {
        // only if can be purchased
        if ($product->is_purchasable()) {
            // show qty +/- with button
            ob_start();
            woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart();
            $button = ob_get_clean();
            // modify button so that AJAX add-to-cart script finds it
            $replacement = sprintf('data-product_id="%d" data-quantity="1" $1 ajax_add_to_cart add_to_cart_button product_type_simple ', $product->id);
            $button = preg_replace('/(class="single_add_to_cart_button)/', $replacement, $button);
        }
    }
    return $button;
}
// add the required JavaScript
function custom_woo_after_shop_loop() {
    ?>

    <script>
    jQuery(function($) {
    <?php /* when product quantity changes, update quantity attribute on add-to-cart button */ ?>
    $("form.cart").on("change", "input.qty", function() {
        $(this.form).find("button[data-quantity]").data("quantity", this.value);
    });
    <?php /* remove old "view cart" text, only need latest one thanks! */ ?>
    $(document.body).on("adding_to_cart", function() {
        $("a.added_to_cart").remove();
    });
    });
    </script>

    <?php
}
```